# Unable to Upload file to S3 using putObject

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am trying to upload a file to S3 using putObject(bucketName,BucketKeyOrPrefix,File), There is no error in this operation but still, i cannot see the file uploaded in s3 .The same s3client reference is working for deleteObject.
How can i identify the issue here? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validate the identity running the code has `s3:PutObject` permission and then modify the code to add a log statement in case of errors.

```
try {
  const res = await s3.putObject({
    Bucket: bucketName,
    Key: <yourKey>,
    Body: fs.createReadStream(<Your file>)
  }).promise();
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err);
}
```